# Compile-time checking for jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

does anyone know of a tool that can help with compile-time checking of jQuery selectors? Specifically I'm thinking of the number of times code hasn't worked because I've misspelled an ID or classname, or got the syntax wrong in a selector.
E.g. if my HTML page has

```
<style>
.weirdClassName { }
</style>
<div id="someElement"></div>
```

And I then try to use $("#someElemnt") or $(".wierdClassName") I want it to warn me (or even fail compilation) because I'm referring to an element or class that doesn't exist. And certainly if I do something syntactically incorrect such as $("a[b)").  Obviously there are times when the former two selectors may be useful even if there is no compile-time HTML/CSS that would match, so there would need to be some way of marking that it as intended (even if it's just $("#" + "someElemnt"), but 99% of the time it's a typo and it would save a lot of time if it could be caught at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a given element exists with

```
$(selector).length
```

It will return 0 if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, but how does that answer my question about compile-time checking?